# import data Oracle-SQL from files in different folders

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, import

I want to import  many different files from different folders. Each folder has a number. There is a folder structure like:

E:\data\drivers_v1\drivers\1

[image]

There is one specific isssue with the folder-structure: some folders are missing. For example, de folders 4 until 9.

In each folder there are exact 200 files. Each file has a number like 1.csv, 2.csv etc. I want to import these files in one table. After the import a have the same number of tables as folders.

I tried several pl/sql code. The last option was:

```
DECLARE
    TELLER_1   INTEGER := 1;
    TELLER_DR  INTEGER :=10;
    AANTAL_SEC INTEGER;
    ctt0 varchar(30000);
    ctt1 varchar(30000);
    ctt2 varchar(30000);
    ctt3 varchar(30000);

BEGIN   

FOR TELLER_DR IN 10..12 LOOP

execute immediate 'create directory dat_dir as ''E:\data\drivers_v1\drivers\'||TELLER_DR||'''';
execute immediate 'create directory log_dir as ''E:\data\drivers_v1\drivers\'||TELLER_DR||'''';
execute immediate 'create directory bad_dir as ''E:\data\drivers_v1\drivers\'||TELLER_DR||'''';

ctt0 := '

          CREATE TABLE DRIVER_'||TELLER_DR||'_DEF
          (
          DRIVER_CHAR VARCHAR2(255),
          DRIVER_INT INTEGER,
          RIT INTEGER,
          SEC INTEGER,
          X NUMBER,
          Y NUMBER
          )
          '
          ;

execute immediate ctt0;

        FOR teller_1 IN 1 .. 200 LOOP
                   ctt1 := '
                              CREATE TABLE driver_rit_'||TELLER_1||'
                              (
                              x VARCHAR2 (255),
                              y VARCHAR2 (255)
                              )
                              organization external
                              (
                                 type oracle_loader
                                 default directory dat_dir
                                 access parameters
                                 ( records delimited by 0x''0A''
                                   BADFILE bad_dir:''driver_rit_'||TELLER_1||'_BAD.TXT''
                                   DISCARDFILE dat_dir:''driver_rit_'||TELLER_1||'_DCF.TXT''
                                   LOGFILE dat_dir:''driver_rit_'||TELLER_1||'_LOG.TXT''
                                   SKIP 1
                                   fields terminated by '',''
                                   MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
                                 )
                              LOCATION ('''||TELLER_1||'.csv'')
                              ) reject limit 2000
                           '
                            ;  

                        execute immediate ctt1;

                        ctt2 := '      
                              insert into DRIVER_'||TELLER_DR||'_DEF
                                (select 
                                ''DRIVER_'||TELLER_DR||''',
                                '||TELLER_DR||',
                                '||TELLER_1||',
                                ROWNUM,
                                X , 
                                Y
                                from driver_rit_'||TELLER_1||'
                                )
                             '
                            ;  
                        execute immediate ctt2;

                        ctt3 := 'drop table driver_rit_'||TELLER_1||'';
                        execute immediate ctt3;

       END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

this code doesn't work. 
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at line 16
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"

Who has a suggestion for a sql or pl/sql script?

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: You just need to write a script depending on your OS. Everything would remain same, except the `dumpfile` parameter value. You just need to loop it through all the file names. So, you just to write an `impdp` statement and loop it through the dump files. In `UNIX`, it would be an easy think with a shell script.

Comment: Try dropping directories `dat_dir`, `log_dir` and `bad_dir` at the end of the script or simply use `create OR REPLACE directory...`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works!!